# how to read the CPU utilization in k8s LENS

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, hpa

It may sound like a naive question, I am running some load testing on one of the deployments on k8s. So to get an idea of the CPU utilization, I opened LENS HPA and CPU utilization is being shown like this

[image]

can anyone please tell me how to understand this number, earlier it was 380/50% for CPU.

I just want to get an idea of what does this number means, if it is 380/50, is my CPU not big enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means probably the same as the output from the `kubectl describe hpa {hpa-name}:`

```
$ kubectl describe hpa php-apache
Name:                                                  php-apache
...
Metrics:                                               ( current / target )
  resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):  60% (120m) / 50%
```

It means that CPU has consumption increased to to x % of the request - [good example and explanation in the Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#increase-load):

> Within a minute or so, you should see the higher CPU load; for example:
>
> ```
> NAME         REFERENCE                     TARGET      MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
> php-apache   Deployment/php-apache/scale   305% / 50%  1         10        1          3m
> ```
>
> and then, more replicas. For example:
>
> ```
> NAME         REFERENCE                     TARGET      MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
> php-apache   Deployment/php-apache/scale   305% / 50%  1         10        7          3m
> ```
>
> Here, CPU consumption has increased to 305% of the request.

So in your example **(380%/50%)** it means that you setup HPA to maintain an average CPU utilization across pods to **50%** (by increasing and decreasing number of replicas - updating the deployment) and CPU consumption has increased to **380%** so the deployment will be resized automatically.

Also check:

- [Horizontal Pod Autoscaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/)
- [HorizontalPodAutoscaler Walkthrough](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your contribution. I have a question, at the time when current is 305% and 7 replications are pulled up (as in the example), should the percentage shown in current go down?
I'm doing some tests with HPA and I notice that when the target threshold is exceeded, and HPA increases the replications by a certain pod, the percentage shown in current still remains almost the same as before (i.e. high), despite I inject a constant load, I don't understand if it is a problem with my cluster or if it is correct like this.
I thank anyone who will clarify this question of mine.